# Include values of different table in django models

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to check if files reported in one system exist in a different system. The models belong to different tables in different **databases**.  They have no relationship other than the name in common.

I'm using django rest framework to serialize the values of one table and I'd like to include the values of the other table in one efficient way. The way I'm currently doing, makes too many queries! My question is: **Is there a way to improve this performance issue?**

Here is an example of what I have

```
# model1
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

# model2 (different database)
class Files(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

And my view set is

```
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Inventory.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
```

I managed to get the result as I said (not efficiently, though) in two different ways:

1) Including the fields in the serializer

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    has_png = serializers.SerializerMethodField('has_png')
    has_jpg = serializers.SerializerMethodField('has_jpg')

    def has_png(self, product):
        # I wish I could avoid this code duplication too...
        # I'm basically using the same code in two functions
        files = Files.objects.filter(name=product.name)
        filtered_files = files.filter(filename__startswith='png')
        return filtered_files.exists()

    def has_bam(self, product):
        files = Files.objects.filter(name=product.name)
        filtered_files = files.filter(filename__istartswith='jpg')
        return filtered_files.exists()
    Meta:
        model = Product
```

2) Including properties in my model1 which is serialized

```
class Product(modes.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def _get_png(self):
        # I tried to cache this query in a different function but didn't work
        files = Files.objects.filter(name=self.name)
        filtered_files = files.filter(filename__istartswith='png')
        return filtered_files.exists()

    def _get_jpg(self):
        files = Files.objects.filter(name=self.name)
        filtered_files = files.filter(filename__istartswith='jpg')
        return filtered_files.exists()

    has_png = property(_get_png)
    has_jpg = property(_get_jpg)
```

and then I add in the serializer:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    has_fastq = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    has_bam = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    Meta:
        model = Product
```

Comment: `file_format` is it field ov your `Files` models? i don't see such filter for djang can you get link on the doc, if it is not field

Comment: Yes, sorry. I will edit that field to be consistent to the model here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to use [cached_property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.functional)

```
from django.db.models.functions import Lower
from django.utils.functional import cached_property


class Product(modes.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    @cached_property
    def file_formats(self):
        files = Files.objects.filter(name=self.name)
        files = files.annotate(lower_format=Lower('file_format')))
        return files.values_list('lower_format', flat=True)

    def _get_png(self):
        return 'png' in self.file_formats

    def _get_jpg(self):
        return 'jpg' in self.file_formats

    has_png = property(_get_png)
    has_jpg = property(_get_jpg)
```

Comment: That looks good. I will try on Monday since I don't have access to the code now. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I just changed the function `.list` to `values_list` and it's working like a charm. I edited your answer to be all good for other users. Thanks!